# Node.js Multer upload array missing single file

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I am currently using Multer to upload multiple files at once. When I log the incoming files I get every file that I want to upload, but it only uploads missing 1 file. So when i upload 7 files, 6 are actually uploaded, when I upload 6 files, 5 are uploaded and so on.

The files that I upload are also not too big. It starts when I want to upload more than 4 files.

I don't see what I am doing wrong.

**My Controller:**

```
var uploadMemory = multer().array("memory");

const addMemory = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);

    uploadMemory(req, res, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.json({
                status: "succes"
            });
        }
    });
};
```

**My multer function:**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads",
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "." + file.mimetype.split("/")[1]);
    }
});

app.use(multer({ storage: storage }).any());
```

Comment: Are you getting the same result when trying with Postman?

Comment: @DanieleMolinari Yes, it's the same. There is always 1 file missing.

Comment: Then you can discard the Angular code in your question, please add more relevant code from the backend. What you posted seems ok.